# A clarification of partial derivatives

Tags: notation, partial-derivative

I have been wondering, why do textbooks say things like "partial derivative with respect to $x$", for say a function from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The function could easily have been written with variables like $a,b,c,d$. Shouldn't it really be "partial derivative with respect to the first coordinate"? Is there a textbook that doesn't make this error?

Comment: I don't know your textbook but I'm assuming that the function is written as $f: \mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R$, $f(x,y,z,t) = ...$ where it would make sense to talk about a partial derivative with respect to $x$. If we have $f(x) = f(x_1, \dots, x_n)$, then it would not make much sense. So it really depends on how the variables are named.

Comment: Yeah you are right. The first coordinate can be called anything. It's just customary to call it $x$, since authors trust people will understand what they mean. Did you ever have this question about functions $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$? They always say $x$ and $y$ in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is customary to *define* the first coordinate as x. Had they chosen to define the first coordinate as a, then it would say the partial derivative with respect to a. You'll never find a partial derivative with respect to a coordinate where that coordinate has not yet been assigned a variable. Does that make sense?
In other words, first we define the $i^{th}$ coordinate as some variable, and then we say "the partial derivative with respect to ____". The blank space being the given variable.